# Passing pointer array to function

Tags: c++

i have the following situation. the following program although it compiles just fine when i run it, it stops working. can anyone please help me to find the problem? i think i'm using the wrong pointer into the function but i don't know how to fix it and make it work

```
#include <fstream>
//some other includes
using namespace std;

struct Book{
    string id;
    string title;
    string authorName;
    string authorSurname;
    };

int load(Book* booksInfo)
{
int count = 0;
ifstream fin;
fin.open("myfile.txt");

if (!fin.is_open())
{
    cout << "Unable to open myfile.txt file\n";
    exit(1);
}

while (fin.good())
{   
    getline(fin, booksInfo[count].id, '#'); 
    getline(fin, booksInfo[count].title, '#'); 
    getline(fin, booksInfo[count].authorName, '#'); 
    getline(fin, booksInfo[count].authorSurname, '#'); 

    count++;
} //end while

fin.close(); 

return 0;
} //end load()

//some other functions here

int main()
{
Book * bookInfo;
bookInfo = (Book*) malloc(sizeof(Book)*100);

//some code here

load(bookInfo);

    //some code here

return 0;
} //end main
```

Comment: What does "stops working" mean?

Comment: In C++ it is preferred (in some cases necessary) to use new instead of malloc. Also you may want to look into STL containers (most notably std::vector)

Comment: Why malloc? Don't use malloc. Use new.

Comment: Why new? Don't use new. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2010 and when i run my program a window comes out which it sais:

Comment: a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Comment: You crashed. Get rid of the malloc. Write `Book* bookInfo = new Book[100];` or `Book bookInfo[100]` to start with. Later, you may consider switching to an std::vector.

Comment: @DanielDaranas, I'd do it the other way around. Start with a vector and learn how to do it manually properly later. Then you write better and easier code from the beginning.

Comment: @chris Either thing away from malloc will be good. What I recommend is my experience, and it worked well for me. In any case, std::vector should be the choice; but understanding how to correctly allocate a native array is a must.

Comment: @DanielDaranas, What you recommend is my experience as well, but it took me reading SO to eventually switch. People tend to use and like what they already know, and vectors are usually even easier to use than new. It's definitely important to learn both, but might as well get them hooked on the better one and then they can learn why it works, rather than a mostly non-solution.

Comment: Also, your input loop is bad; there's a good chance it will add a garbled book as the last entry every time.

Answer (score 3):

It is UB to use `malloc` to allocate non POD types, in your case book instances will contain some garbage in strings, because there was no `std::string` constructor called. And it won't be just garbage strings, it will be most likely garbage pointer pointing to some random locations.
You should use `std::vector` or at least `new` if you really need to allocate memory manually, to create new `Book` instances in a heap.
And if you really, really must use `malloc`, you can use placement `new` to create valid `std::string`s in raw memory you have allocated somehow (by `malloc` in your case).

Comment: If they must `malloc` they can use [Placement New](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) to initialize

Comment: @Mgetz I bet this is not the case, but adding a note on that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector` to store your list of books:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
//some other includes
using namespace std;

struct Book{
    string id;
    string title;
    string authorName;
    string authorSurname;
    };

vector<Book> load()
{
    ifstream fin;
    Book book;
    vector<Book> books;
    fin.open("myfile.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open myfile.txt file\n";
        return books;
    }

    while (fin.good())
    {   
        getline(fin, book.id, '#'); 
        getline(fin, book.title, '#'); 
        getline(fin, book.authorName, '#'); 
        getline(fin, book.authorSurname, '#'); 
        books.push_back(book);
    } //end while

    fin.close(); 

    return books;
} //end load()

//some other functions here

int main()
{
    vector<Book> books = load();
    return 0;
} //end main
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
Book* bookInfo = new Book[100];
```

instead. This is because, in C++, a `struct` is an object (just like a `class`), and calling malloc on anything other than *plain old data* is *undefined behaviour*.

Remember to free your memory using `delete[] bookInfo;` (note carefully the square brackets). If you use `delete` on it's own, that's a little more *undefined behaviour*.

Also make sure that you don't read more than 100 lines; or you'll overflow the array: yet more *undefined behaviour*.

Finally, consider using a standard template library container like `std::vector`.

Comment: thanx for your point! i wonder, if i use "new" instead of malloc what can use instead of realloc??

Comment: @Panagiotis, Technically placement new, but seriously, use a vector.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Book bookInfo[100];
```

This avoids heap allocation altogether and should serve your purposes.